# Concrete Class 'Inject' is throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring-mvc, service, interface, controller, illegalargumentexception

I have a service interface **UserService** and an implementing class **UserServiceImpl**. When I try to inject **UserServiceImpl** to a variable in a controller class, it throws an **NoSuchBeanDefinitionException**. But when I inject **UserService** interface, it works fine.

The interface **UserService** is annotated with **@Service**. The implementing class doesn't have any annotation as such.

Confused why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation should have the annotation. Not the interface. And the controller should depend on the interface, not on the implementation. That's what would allow Spring to inject an AOP proxy, allowing for transactions, security, etc:

```
public interface UserService {
    ...
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    ...
}


@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I read that I could annotate the interface as well and it wouldn't make any difference. But thanks a lot for your insight into the problem.